# ProgressDialog not getting started in main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I made an app which can upload some data to my database. In Activity, in which the user will enter data to be uploaded, i created a ProgressDialog. The ProgressDialog is created inside the onClick() method.

In theory, it will be created because I'm not trying to make a ProgerssDialog in a thread other than Main UI Thread.
Still, it's not being shown. I don't know why.

```
package com.example.demoapp;

import android.widget.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText planID, name, number, address, handsetValue, planAmount, validity, pass, confirm_pass;
private Button call;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private String response;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean startup = prefs.getBoolean("FIRST_STARTUP", true);
    if(startup)
    {
    planID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.planIDET);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameET);
    number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactET);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressET);
    handsetValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.handsetValueET);
    planAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.planAmountET);
    validity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.validityET);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    confirm_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_Button);

    planID.setText("");
    name.setText("");
    number.setText("");
    address.setText("");
    handsetValue.setText("");
    planAmount.setText("");
    validity.setText("");
    pass.setText("");
    confirm_pass.setText("");


    call.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(pass.getText().toString().equals(confirm_pass.getText().toString()))
    {
        ProgressDialog  progress = ProgressDialog.show(v.getContext(), "Please wait...", "Connecting to server", true, true);

        String query = "INSERT INTO user_info (name, password, address, plan_id, contact, handset_value, plan_amount, validity) "
            + "VALUES('" + name.getText() + "','"+ pass.getText() +"','" + address.getText() + "','" + planID.getText() + "','" + number.getText() + "','" + handsetValue.getText() + "','" + planAmount.getText() + "','" + validity.getText() + "');";


    ConnectDBThread connect = new ConnectDBThread(query, Resources.INSERT);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(connect);
    t1.start();
    //####################################//
    Log.i("onClick() ThreadName",String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()));

    while(true)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}



        if(Resources.serverResponse!=null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("SERVER", Resources.serverResponse);
            prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("FIRST_STARTUP", false);
            editor.putString("USERNAME", name.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("USERPASS", pass.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();

            //--- PROGRESSBAR STOPPED
            progress.dismiss();

            break;

        }

    }//LOOP
    }

    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password mismatch!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}// onClick()


}
```

Here, ConnectDBThread is an implementation of Runnable interface which connects to the server and posts a query along with data.

If I created ProgressDialog outside of If statement in onClick(), then app executes query first. After completion of query, it shows ProgressDialog.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: did you do the necessary checks if the Button ID of the one you click is that R.id.submit_Button? Does the Thread execute? Is the pass the correct one so the if is entered?

Comment: Yes. Everything is running fine. The data is securely uploaded to database. But the ProgressDialog is not being shown.

Comment: try to debug it cause i have check the code and i have try to create a progress dialog in onClick same as you have did and its working fine in my code.

Comment: Inside the onClick() method, outside If statement, if I create the ProgressDialog  then its working.

But not inside the If statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the context of the ProgressDialog. From design perspective I believe it is better to declare the ProgressDialog as an instance variable.

```
public class YourClass{

  private ProgressDialog progressDialog; // instance variable
  ....
}
```

And then in the click method create it like this:

```
// I believe the main issue is with the context you bind to the progressDialog
// provide the activity as context as an Activity extends Context
progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Connecting to server", true, true);
```

And lastly do not put a while loop like that inside the onClick method. It will cause the button to be sticky which is not desired and will also make UI unresponsive. Make your ConnectDBThread an **AsyncTask** and update the UI (like dismiss the dialog) from there through **onPostExecute** once background process is completed in **doInBackground**.

Here is a proposed solution:

```
public class InsertTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

     ProgressDialog dialog;
     Context ctx;

     public InsertTask(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
     }

     protected void onPreExecute(Void result) {
         // do UI work here
         dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "Please wait...", "Connecting to server", true, true);

     }

     protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {


        // do insert operation here ... 
        String username  = args[0];
        String password = args[1];

        ......      
        String query = .... // generate the query
        String serverResponse = doDBInsert(query); // create a method to run the query and return response

        return serverResponse;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         // do UI work here
         // display your serverResponse(result) somewhere if needed
         if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
         }
     }
 }
```

Inside onClick Method:

```
//If check condition is met (password = confirm password)
 new InsertTask(getApplicationContext()).execute(username, password, address ...);
```

Comment: I created the ProgressDialog before the If statement, and It's working. How?

Comment: I believe the problem is your while loop inside the code. You will need to use AsyncTask to make it work. The design you are using to get the job done is wrong.

Comment: Few moment back, I made an update.

I made a separate thread that starts OnClickListener in it. By using Handler, i sent a message to the calling thread. Now the ProgressDialog is being shown.
But i'm still unable to dismiss() it.
I'll let you know, if i do.

Comment: I have a put a proposed solution for you. When trying to dismiss your dialog make sure to check if dialog.isShowing() is true before dismissing the dialog.

Comment: Here's an update.
Now I'm using Handler to send message from ConnectDBThread to Main UI Thread. Now it's getting started, but unable to close.

It's throwing some error like, "This message is already in use".