# ProgressDialog is displayed only once and then no longer works

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I am developing a kotlin application that processes images. At each user interaction on the image processing steps I added a progressDialog to give a visual response to the user of what is being done, however it only shows on the first progress. In the second onwards, even though it is no longer in that processing step, it still does not show the progress. I already switched to ProgressBar and the error still persists. Can someone explain to me the reason and the solution for this?

code:

```
private fun regionBackground() {

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme)
    progressDialog.setMessage( "Salved draw...") //First Progress
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false)
    progressDialog.show()
    srcOriginal = Imgcodecs.imread(currentPhotoPath)
    markers = Mat.zeros(srcOriginal.rows(), srcOriginal.cols(), CvType.CV_32S)
    for (value in 0..drawingview.pointsToDrawX.size - 1) {
        markers.put(
            drawingview.pointsToDrawY[value].toInt(),
            drawingview.pointsToDrawX[value].toInt(),
            1.0
        )
    }
    drawingview.pointsToDrawYStepTwo.clear()
    drawingview.pointsToDrawXStepTwo.clear()
    Handler().postDelayed({
        progressDialog.dismiss()        }, 1000)

}

private fun regionOfInterest() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme)
    progressDialog.setMessage( "Segment image...")
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false)
    progressDialog.show()
    for (value in 0..drawingview.pointsToDrawXStepTwo.size - 1) {
        markers.put(
            drawingview.pointsToDrawYStepTwo[value].toInt(),
            drawingview.pointsToDrawXStepTwo[value].toInt(),
            255.0
        )
    }
    ....
    progressDialog.dismiss()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful that you show us the order in which those functions are being called. I think that a possible cause is that the first progressDialog.dismiss() is being called after the second progressDialog.show() was called. So it dismisses it too fast before it finishes (and it looks like its not being called).

Can you try debugging to see this is not making things wrong (the order)? I know they are different objects, but once I had a similar error.

Hope it helps.

Comment: first the regionBackground is called, upon completion the user presses a button to call the regionOfInterest

Comment: I put a handler in the second method and it really showed up. only that it only appeared a long time after the first one was closed, so even if the first one is closed, it is as if it were running something that only starts to show the second one after that something stops running, and I suspect that this something is these loops in execution.

Comment: it seems to be a problem with the threads, i don't know why. But I have read other people having similar issues like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691797/progressdialog-not-getting-started-in-main-thread